# How would you look at developing an algorithm for this hotel problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a problem I am working on for a programming course and I am having trouble developing an algorithm to suit the problem.  Here it is:

> You are going on a long trip. You start on the road at mile post 0. Along the way there are n
>   hotels, at mile posts a1 < a2 < ... < an, where each ai is measured from the starting point. The
>   only places you are allowed to stop are at these hotels, but you can choose which of the hotels
>   you stop at. You must stop at the final hotel (at distance an), which is your destination.
>   You'd ideally like to travel 200 miles a day, but this may not be possible (depending on the spacing
>   of the hotels). If you travel x miles during a day, the penalty for that day is (200 - x)^2. You want
>   to plan your trip so as to minimize the total penalty that is, the sum, over all travel days, of the
>   daily penalties.
>   Give an efficient algorithm that determines the optimal sequence of hotels at which to stop.

So, my intuition tells me to start from the back, checking penalty values, then somehow match them going back the forward direction (resulting in an O(n^2) runtime, which is optimal enough for the situation).

Anyone see any possible way to make this idea work out or have any ideas on possible implmentations?

Comment: A feeble piece of optimisation, not even worth an answer, but if two adjacent hotels are exactly 200 miles away, you can remove one of them.

Comment: @biziclop, you mean they are on opposite sides of the road?

Comment: From [Andrew Clark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951253/3789665), I deduce there was an example of `{0, 200, 400, 600, 601}`.

Comment: Is `200 miles` an upper limit? (From a [comment of dcfc_rph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950956/how-would-you-look-at-developing-an-algorithm-for-this-hotel-problem#comment5523220_4951253) : no.) If it is: With hotels at (0,) 22, 200, 222: am I allowed to travel 200, 178, and 200 miles?

Comment: `intuition tells me to start from the back` why would the direction matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `x` is a marker number, `ax` is the mileage to that marker, and `px` is the minimum penalty to get to that marker, you can calculate `pn` for marker `n` if you know `pm` for all markers `m` before `n`.

To calculate `pn`, find the minimum  of `pm + (200 - (an - am))^2` for all markers `m` where `am < an` and `(200 - (an - am))^2` is less than your current best for `pn` (last part is optimization).

For the starting marker `0`, `a0 = 0` and `p0 = 0`, for marker `1`, `p1 = (200 - a1)^2`.  With that starting information you can calculate `p2`, then `p3` etc. up to `pn`.

**edit**: Switched to Java code, using the example from OP's comment.  Note that this does not have the optimization check described in second paragraph.

```
public static void printPath(int path[], int i) {
    if (i == 0) return;
    printPath(path, path[i]);
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int hotelList[] = {0, 200, 400, 600, 601};
    int penalties[] = {0, (int)Math.pow(200 - hotelList[1], 2), -1, -1, -1};
    int path[] = {0, 0, -1, -1, -1};
    for (int i = 2; i <= hotelList.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            int tempPen = (int)(penalties[j] + Math.pow(200 - (hotelList[i] - hotelList[j]), 2));
            if(penalties[i] == -1 || tempPen < penalties[i]){
                penalties[i] = tempPen;
                path[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < hotelList.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Hotel: " + hotelList[i] + ", penalty: " + penalties[i] + ", path: ");
        printPath(path, i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Hotel: 200, penalty: 0, path: 1 
Hotel: 400, penalty: 0, path: 1 2 
Hotel: 600, penalty: 0, path: 1 2 3 
Hotel: 601, penalty: 1, path: 1 2 4
```

Comment: You can move more than 200 per day

Comment: That is correct, but each step in the algorithm looks back to the minimal penalties for the previous hotels.  For example it is possible that the optimal solution for `a2` is to skip `a1`, but the optimal solution for `a3` is `start -> a1 -> a3` and this algorithm will find that sequence.

Comment: I think I see a problem here, maybe its accounted for in some way but I've missed it. Consider:

A-------B-------C-------D-E

Where A, B, C, and D are all 200 miles apart, and E is 1 mile from D.  If I'm not mistaken, your algorithm will take A->B->C->D->E, where D should be skipped in order to produce a penalty of 199^2.  Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: That is incorrect, when the algorithm gets to `E` it will see `pC = 0` with a potential `pE` of 1 ( (200 - 201)^2 ), and will choose that over `pD = 0` with a potential `pE` of (200 - 1)^2.

Comment: @Andrew Unless my implementation in java is incorrect...this did not work

Comment: @dcfc_rph Put your full implementation into your question and maybe I or someone else can see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @Andrew Check back later tonight, at some point after 11:30pm est if you can, and I'll have it up (class then work).

Comment: @Andrew You, sir, are a genius.  I modified it to work with any given motel input, as required by the assignment.  You helped me out greatly, thanks for everything.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you can solve this problem with **dynamic programming**. The subproblem is the following:

`d(i)` : The minimum penalty possible when travelling from the start to hotel `i`.

The recursive formula is as follows:

`d(0) = 0` where 0 is the starting position.

```
d(i) = min_{j=0, 1, ... , i-1} ( d(j) + (200-(ai-aj))^2)
```

The minimum penalty for reaching hotel `i` is found by trying all stopping places for the previous day, adding today's penalty and taking the minimum of those.

In order to find the path, we store in a separate array (path[]) which hotel we had to travel from in order to achieve the minimum penalty for that particular hotel. By traversing the array backwards (from path[n]) we obtain the path.

The runtime is O(n^2).

Comment: I take that last comment back.  This will work; however, consider the following.   A---B---C---D-E   A, B, C, D are all 200 apart and E is at mile marker 601.  Your algorithm will yield a penalty of 199^2, when ideally you would go A->B->C->E, yielding a penalty of 1^2.  Unless I am reading this wrong...

Comment: For the test case of (A=0, B=200, C=400, D=600, E=601): My algorithm will achieve a penalty of 0 up to D. When selecting the how to travel to E, it will choose the minimum cost among d(D)+199^2, d(C)+1^2, d(B)+201^2, d(A)+401^2. Since all of d(A),d(B),d(C),d(D)=0, d(C)+1^2=1 has the lowest penalty, hence my algorithm will travel from C->E as the last movement.

Comment: I seem to be understanding the recursion a little better, but how it actually determines the best path to take is a little hazy to me...

Answer (score 4):

This is equivalent to finding the shortest path between two nodes in a directional acyclic graph. Dijkstra's algorithm will run in O(n^2) time.

Your intuition is better, though. Starting at the back, calculate the minimum penalty of stopping at that hotel. The first hotel's penalty is just (200-(200-x)^2)^2. Then, for each of the other hotels (in reverse order), scan forward to find the lowest-penalty hotel. A simple optimization is to stop as soon as the penalty costs start *increasing*, since that means you've overshot the global minimum.

Comment: How is it like finding the shortest path between two nodes? They're all set in a line, and you got a constraint about how many hotels you can pass until you stop.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you're incorrect.  You can theoretically pass every hotel and go straight to the end, you'll just have a possibly obnoxious penalty.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer Imagine that every hotel is connected to every hotel further down the road by an edge with a weight that equals the penalty of skipping there directly.

Comment: Why do you start at the back though? It looks pretty much indifferent to me which end you start from.

Comment: @sysrqb "Starting at the back, calculate the minimum penalty of stopping at that hotel."  Stopping at that hotel from where?

Comment: @biziclip The way I see it, you need to go both directions.  This way just seemed more logical to me since your last step takes you in the forward direction.  /shrug

Comment: Order doesn't matter, but I went with the OPs suggestion-- "if I stop at this hotel, I'm X penalty away from the end" and "if I stop at this hotel, I'm X penalty away from the beginning" are essentially the same.

Comment: @dcfc_rph: The last hotel's penalty is the cost of going from that hotel to the end. The second to last hotel's penalty is the minimum of (the penalty of going to the last hotel plus the penalty of going from the last hotel to the end) and (the penalty of going to the end). And so on.

Comment: @biziclop  It's not a constant penalty. If you get to the hotel ai on day 1, it's (200-X)^2 ... but if you get there on day 2 it's a relative distance from the day before. Besides, you can't put the penalty weight on the edges, because it won't sum up right (even if you disregard what i just said) ... And that's because of the simple fact that: (200-x)^2 + (200-y)^2 != (200-(x+y))^2 .... which is what you really need if you pas 2 hotels in 1 day.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer No, you're misunderstanding the graph representation. The graph's definition is this: For every `k < l`, let an edge run between `ak` and `al` with the weight of (200-dist(ak,al))^2. If you construct the graph this way, it is indeed a shortest path problem. However, A* is likely to fail because our distance metric isn't really a metric, as it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: Right, if you build the weights between each hotel to all the following, then it will work as minimum path on a directed graph. Build complexity would be O(N^2)... Add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it as easily as sysrqb states.

On a side note, there is really no difference to starting from start or end; the goal is to find the minimum amount of stops each way, where each stop is as close to 200m as possible.

The question as stated seems to allow travelling beyond 200m per day, and the penalty is equally valid for over or under (since it is squared).  This prefers an overage of miles per day rather than underage, since the penalty is equal, but the goal is closer.

However, given this layout

```
A ----- B----C-------D------N
0       190  210     390    590
```

It is not always true.  It is better to go to B->D->N for a total penalty of only `(200-190)^2 = 100`.  Going further via C->D->N gives a penalty of `100+400=500`.

The answer looks like a full breadth first search with active pruning if you already have an optimal solution to reach point P, removing all solutions thus far where

```
sum(penalty-x) > sum(penalty-p)  AND  distance-to-x <= distance-to-p - 200
```

This would be an O(n^2) algorithm

---

Something like...

- Quicksort all hotels by distance from start (discard any that have distance > hotelN)
- Create an array/list of solutions, each containing (ListOfHotels, I, DistanceSoFar, Penalty)
- Inspect each hotel in order, for each hotel_I
    Calculate penalty to I, starting from each prior solution
- Pruning
    For each prior solution that is beyond 200 distanceSoFar from
    current, and Penalty>current.penalty, remove it from list
- loop

Comment: Exactly, this is the exact problem I am having is how to overcome this problem. I'm not sure to judge the trip as a whole instead of step by step while keeping runtime at O(n^2) *wrote this before your edit*

Comment: Could you add a little more to your algorithm explanation?  I'm beginning to understand it but I don't think I'm seeing it clearly.  (I'll be writing in java, if that means anything here...ha)

Comment: If you were running in reverse (as I specified), the cost at D would be 0, the cost at C would be 20^2, the cost at B would be 0, and the cost at A would be 10^2.

Comment: @sysrqb - I still don't see how starting at end or beginning would matter at all

Answer (score 1):

Following is the MATLAB code for hotel problem.

```
clc
clear all

% Data     
% a = [0;50;180;150;50;40];    
% a = [0, 200, 400, 600, 601];    
  a = [0,10,180,350,450,600];    
% a = [0,1,2,3,201,202,203,403];

n = length(a);    
opt(1) = 0;    
prev(1)= 1;

for i=2:n
    opt(i) =Inf;
    for j = 1:i-1
        if(opt(i)>(opt(j)+ (200-a(i)+a(j))^2))
            opt(i)= opt(j)+ (200-a(i)+a(j))^2;
            prev(i) = j; 
        end
    end
    S(i) = opt(i);
end

k = 1;
i = n;
sol(1) = n;

while(i>1)
   k = k+1;
   sol(k)=prev(i);
   i = prev(i);   
end

for i =k:-1:1
    stops(i) = sol(i);
end
stops
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 of 2

Sub-problem:

In this scenario, "C(j)" has been considered as sub-problem for minimum penalty gained up to the hotel "ai" when "0<=i<=n". The required value for the problem is "C(n)".

Algorithm to find minimum total penalty:

If the trip is stopped at the location "aj" then the previous stop will be "ai" and the value of i and should be less than j. Then all the possibilities of "ai", has been follows:

C(j) min{C(i)+(200-(aj-ai))^2}, 0<=i<=j.

- Initialize the value of "C(0)" as "0" and “a0" as "0" to ﬁnd the remaining values.
- To ﬁnd the optimal route, increase the value of "j" and "i" for each iteration of and use this detail to backtrack from "C(n)".

Here, "C(n)" refers the penalty of the last hotel (That is, the value of "i" is between "0" and "n").

Pseudocode:

> //Function deﬁnition
>
> Procedure min_tot()
>
> //Outer loop to represent the value of  for j = 1 to n:
>
> //Calculate the distance of each stop C(j) = (200 — aj)^2
>
> //Inner loop to represent the value of for i=1 to j-1:
>
> //Compute total penalty and assign the minimum //total penalty to
>   "c(j)"
>
> C(j) = min (C(i), C(i) + (200 — (aj — ai))^2}
>
> //Return the value of total penalty of last hotel
>
> return C(n)

Step 2 of 2

Explanation:
The above algorithm is used to ﬁnd the minimum total penalty from the starting point to the end point.

- It uses the function "min()" to ﬁnd the total penalty for the each stop in the trip and computes the minimum
  penalty value.

Running time of the algorithm:

This algorithm contains "n" sub-problems and each sub-problem take "O(n)" times to resolve.

- It is needed to compute only the minimum values of "O(n)".
- And the backtracking process takes "O(n)" times.
- The total running time of the algorithm is nxn = n^2 = O(n^2) .

Therefore, this algorithm totally takes "0(n^2)" times to solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this problem recently and wanted to share my solution written in Javascript.

Not dissimilar to the most of the above solutions, I have used dynamic programming approach. To calculate `penalties[i]`, we need to search for such stopping place for the previous day so that the penalty is minimum.
`penalties(i) = min_{j=0, 1, ... , i-1} ( penalties(j) + (200-(hotelList[i]-hotelList[j]))^2)` The solution does **not** assume that the  first penalty is `Math.pow(200 - hotelList[1], 2)`. We don't know whether or not it is optimal to stop at the first top so this assumption should not be made. 
In order to find the optimal path and store all the stops along the way, the helper array `path` is being used. Finally, the array is being traversed backwards to calculate the `finalPath`.

```
function calculateOptimalRoute(hotelList) {
const path = [];
const penalties = [];

for (i = 0; i < hotelList.length; i++) {
    penalties[i] = Math.pow(200 - hotelList[i], 2)
    path[i] = 0
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        const temp = penalties[j] + Math.pow((200 - (hotelList[i] - hotelList[j])), 2)
        if (temp < penalties[i]) {
            penalties[i] = temp;
            path[i] = (j + 1);
        }

    }
}

const finalPath = [];
let index = path.length - 1

while (index >= 0) {
    finalPath.unshift(index + 1);
    index = path[index] - 1;
}
console.log('min penalty is ', penalties[hotelList.length - 1])
console.log('final path is ', finalPath)

return finalPath;

}

// calculateOptimalRoute([20, 40, 60, 940, 1500])
// Outputs [3, 4, 5]

// calculateOptimalRoute([190, 420, 550, 660, 670])
// Outputs [1, 2, 5]

// calculateOptimalRoute([200, 400, 600, 601])
// Outputs [1, 2, 4]

// calculateOptimalRoute([])
// Outputs []
```

Comment: Since this provides the solution to the question, It's good to provide some details about how this code actually works

Comment: Not dissimilar to the first two most up-voted solutions to the problem, I am using a dynamic programming approach. To calculate the penalties[i], I am searching for such stopping place for the previous day so that the penalty is minimum.

Comment: Continued:  `penalties(i) = min_{j=0, 1, ... , i-1} ( penalties(j) + (200-(hotelList[i]-hotelList[j]))^2)` One thing that I would like to emphasise is that, as opposed to the most up-voted solution to this problem, I don't agree that the first penalty should be calculated as `Math.pow(200 - hotelList[1], 2)` We don't know whether or not it is optimal to stop at the first top so this assumption should not be made in my opinion.

Comment: Nice to see the details. I'd suggest please paste your details by editing the original answer rather than in comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question concisely, a PSPACE-complete algorithm is usually considered "efficient" for most Constraint Satisfaction Problems, so if you have an O(n^2) algorithm, that's "efficient".

I think the simplest method, given N total miles and 200 miles per day, would be to divide N by 200 to get X; the number of days you will travel. Round that to the nearest whole number of days X', then divide N by X' to get Y, the optimal number of miles to travel in a day. This is effectively a constant-time operation. If there were a hotel every Y miles, stopping at those hotels would produce the lowest possible score, by minimizing the effect of squaring each day's penalty. For instance, if the total trip is 605 miles, the penalty for travelling 201 miles per day (202 on the last) is 1+1+4 = 6, far less than 0+0+25 = 25 (200+200+205) you would get by minimizing each individual day's travel penalty as you went.

Now, you can traverse the list of hotels. The fastest method would be to simply pick the hotel that is the closest to each multiple of Y miles. It's linear-time and will produce a "good" result. However, I do not think this will produce the "best" result in all cases.

The more complex but foolproof method is to get the two closest hotels to each multiple of Y; the one immediately before and the one immediately after. This produces an array of X' pairs, which can be traversed in all possible permutations in 2^X' time. You can shorten this by applying Dijkstra to a map of these pairs, which will determine the least costly path for each day's travel, and will execute in roughly (2X')^2 time. This will probably be the most efficient algorithm that is guaranteed to produce the optimal result.

Comment: what do you think of the pseudo I just added?

Comment: Both your algorithms would perform pretty poorly on this sequence: 0,199,201,202

Comment: No. If 202 is the endpoint (which I assume because it's the last one), we would discover in the first part of the algorithm that we'll be traveling one day, for 202 miles, and then we'll find a hotel exactly at 202 miles. Score of 4.

Answer (score 0):

As @rmmh mentioned you are finding minimum distance path. Here distance is penalty ( 200-x )^2

So you will try to find a stopping plan by finding minimum penalty.

Lets say D(ai) gives distance of ai from starting point

***P(i) = min { P(j) + (200 - (D(ai) - D(dj)) ^2 } where j is : 0 <= j < i***

From a casual analysis it looks to be

O(n^2) algorithm ( = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + .... + n ) = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

As a proof of concept, here is my JavaScript solution in Dynamic Programming without nested loops.

1. We start at zero miles.
2. We find the next stop by keeping the penalty as low as we can by comparing the penalty of a current hotel in the loop to the previous hotel's penalty.
3. Once we have our current minimum, we have found our stop for the day. We assign this point as our next starting point.
4. Optionally, we could keep the total of the penalties:

```js
let hotels = [40, 80, 90, 200, 250, 450, 680, 710, 720, 950, 1000, 1080, 1200, 1480]

function findOptimalPath(arr) {
    let start = 0
    let stops = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Math.pow((start + 200) - arr[i-1], 2) < Math.pow((start + 200) - arr[i], 2)) {
        stops.push(arr[i-1])
        start = arr[i-1]
    }
  }
  console.log(stops)
}
findOptimalPath(hotels)
```

Comment: We need to stop at last hotel 1480, this stops before it

Comment: The last hotel is the destination according to the requirements. We will have to stop at it in any case. The algorithm returns the in-between stops with the minimal penalty cost.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Python solution using Dynamic Programming:

```
distance = [150,180,250,340]

def hotelStop(distance):
    n = len(distance)
    DP = [0 for _ in distance]
    for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
        min_penalty = float("inf")
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            # going from hotel i to j in first day
            x = distance[j]-distance[i]
            penalty = (200-x)**2
            total_pentalty = penalty+ DP[j]
            min_penalty = min(min_penalty,total_pentalty)
        DP[i] = min_penalty
    return DP[0]

hotelStop(distance)
```