# Finding dynamic algorithm to determine optimal sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a homework problem given in the class, and I was wondering if I can get some help.

The problem is that, there is an old man. And he is in a park. The park consist of `c_1, c_2, c_3, ....c_n` benches in a long single route, where `c_1` is closest to the old man, and `c_n` is the last bench that the old man wants to sit on.

He can ideally travel 120 feet without using any help. However, more he travels than 120 feet, he will get tired easily, and less he travel, there is going to be a time disadvantage of sitting on the bench, and getting up. Therefore, for each walk, the penalty for the walk would be `(120-x)^4` where `x` is the length of the walk that he has traveled so far after the last time he took a rest on the bench.

If benches are located each 120 feet apart, that would give him no penalty since he can just take a rest in every bench he encounters, and that will make 120 feet travel, with 0 penalty. Obviously, he can skip the bench, if he thinks he has not traveled 120 feet so far, but only 10 or 20 feet.

The goal is to find an algorithm that gives him the minimum overall penalty in a way using dynamic programming with good time complexity. It does not matter how many times he has taken rest on the bench, but to find a bench list which gives the minimum overall penalty.

Do you think it is possible to achieve better than O(n^2) time complexity? I think this is very similar to the coin problems, or american football scoring problems, but its '(120-x)^4' penalty for every single travel between 2 benches is giving me a headache.

Comment: I remember a similar question here from about a year ago but I can't find it. :(

Comment: I found very similar problem on "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950956/how-would-you-look-at-developing-an-algorithm-for-this-hotel-problem" and that helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've done anything with dynamic programming but I'll take a stab.

Let `P[i]` be the minimum penalty starting from bench `c_i`.

Let `cost(i)` be the penalty for starting from bench `c_i` and going to `c_n`. For `i=n` this will be 0 otherwise it's `(120-x)^4` with `x` being the distance between the benches.

```
for i = n to 1
    P[i] = cost(i)
    for j = i + 1 to n
        P[i] = min(P[i], P[j])
```

We work backwards from the last bench and check for the least cost between walking to the last bench and walking to any bench between the current bench and the last bench.

This runs in O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I have found out so far, but was wondering if I can do this in O(n log n) time using memoization.

Comment: I think there could be an optimization with memoization in the second loop. By building up the penalties from bottom up fashion, last bench wouldn't really need to calculate all possible penalties.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to construct a graph with each chair as a node. Nodes i and j (ij) if distance between them is less than or equal to 120 feet.  Each edge is weighted according to the penalty function.

Now find the shortest distance between start and end nodes.

If the graph is sparse (i.e. benches are sparsely spaced) you can achieve O(nlogn) assuming number of edges is O(n).

Comment: If bench is not sparse, there would be O(n^2) edges ?