# Find the optimal sequence of stops where the number of stops are fixed

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I'm trying to code the following problem:

There are n hotels given at a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> such that 0 < a<sub>0</sub> < a<sub>1</sub> < ... < a<sub>n</sub>. The only places you are allowed to stop are at these hotels, but you can choose which of the hotels you stop at. You must stop at the final hotel (at distance a<sub>n</sub>), which is your destination. Moreover, you are required to complete your journey in exactly d days (i.e have to make d-1 stops in between). If you travel x miles during a day, the cost for that day is x<sup>2</sup>. You want to plan your trip so as to minimize the total cost - that is, the sum, over all travel days, of the daily cost. Find the optimal sequence of hotels at which to stop.

I came up with this dp solution:

Let `dp(i)` be the minimum cost such that the last stop is hotel i.
Base case: `dp(0)=0`.

To compute dp(i), I consider all possible places `0<=k<i`, that we might have stopped before. With the help of below answers, the recurrence relation becomes:

```
for i=1;i<=n;i++
  dp(i)=inf
  prev(i)=undefined
  for k=0;k<i;k++
    if (dp(i)>dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
      dp(i) = dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
      prev(i) = k
```

How do we make sure that this algorithm takes exactly d stops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you look at developing an algorithm for this hotel problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950956/how-would-you-look-at-developing-an-algorithm-for-this-hotel-problem)

Comment: Oh, that's a different question. Here, you must take exactly d days to complete your journey.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence can be backtracked if the previous stops are stored.

```
for i=1;i<=n;i++
 dp(i)=inf //you need to initialize this of course
 prev(i)=undefined
 for k=0;k<i;k++
    if (dp(i)>dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
       dp(i) = dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)
       prev(i) = k //storing the previous stop
```

Then you can backtrack the sequence of `prev(i)`'s:

```
function seq(i):
 if i==0
  return {}
 else
  return append(seq(prev(i)),prev(i))
```

Comment: I think; you meant this for the if condition `(dp(i) > dp(k)+(ai-ak)^2)`

Comment: Oh yes I meant that. Thank you. Fixed it.

Comment: How would you prove that the algorithm indeed gives an optimal sequence of stops?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the "duplicate problem" comment.

Your algorithm would give you the position of stops (int[] k) which would minimize your costs without any consideration of d. I take from your question that you want to convert these k stops to d stops.

There are 3 cases:

1)

> k.length == d;

Problem solved

2)

> k.length < d;

while(k.length!=d)
Find the minimal distance(min) between a(n-1) and a(n) for all n. Start traversal from first hotel. Find the first occurence where a(n) - a(n-1) is min. Now if these two hotels are in your k, find the next occurence, otherwise break your stop to include this as a separate stop in k and repeat.

If you reach end of hotels, you can do this with the second minimal distance and so on until convergence.

3)

> k.length > d;

while(k.length!=d)
This time you need to find minimal distances between two neighbors in k. Merge the two neighbors as one stop, until convergence.

I am not sure if this approach is the optimal one or the right one, but these are my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own `min` operation. When you make a choice, write this choice (index) in parallel array like `aux[i] = k`. After calculation unwind the best sequence in the reverse direction from `aux[n]`

Comment: yup, makes sense. How would you prove that this is indeed the optimal sequence?