# How can I write a Java code that solves this problem by using a design a greedy algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

The problem:

You are going on a long trip. You start on the road at mile post 0. Along the way there are n hotels, numbered as 1 ≤ i ≤ n, at mile posts a 1 < a 2 < . . . < a n , where each a i is measured from the starting point. The only places you are allowed to stop are at these hotels, but you can choose which of the hotels you stop at. You must stop at the final hotel (at distance a n ), which is your destination.
You would ideally like to travel 200 miles a day, but this may not be possible (depending on the spacing of the hotels). If you travel x miles during a day, the penalty for that day is (200 − x) 2 . You want to plan your trip so as to minimize the total penalty, the sum, over all travel days, of the daily penalties.

Does anyone know how I can write a Java code that solves this problem by using a greedy algorithm?

What I have already is:

```
public static void greedy(int[] a) {
    int[] hotel = a;
    int[] cost = new int[hotel.length];
    int[] stop = new int[hotel.length];

    int dist = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hotel.length - 1; i++) {
        dist = a[i + 1] - a[i];
        cost[i] = (int) (Math.pow((200 - hotel[i]), 2));
        stop[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

But I don't know where to go from here..

Comment: 1. Start with a concrete example. 2. "Execute" the example by hand, writing down each step that you go. 3. Try to write code that does each step that you did by hand.  4. Keep working on the code until it gives you the same answer as you got by hand. 5. Test it with more examples.

Comment: For a strikingly similar problem with solutions *not* restricted to `greedy`, see [Long trip, cheap hotels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4950956/3789665).

Comment: Is `200 miles` a hard upper limit for a day trip?

Answer (score 0):

The total distance that you need to cover is `a(n)`, as far as I could understand. As we have to stay in the last hotel, then I would like to propose a greedy solution in reverse mode.

If `a(n) - a(n-1)` cannot be greater than `200` miles. So I would like to pick a hotel `a(i)` which is in the middle of somewhere between `a(n)` and `a(n) - 200`. Now as we are considering a greedy approach, you need to pick that hotel and save this hotel in your visit list.

Now, move forward from there and pick the next hotel where the distance is between `a(i)` and `a(i) - 200` and so on until you reach your starting point.

I am not writing any code as I assume this is homework. However, I think you get the idea. Hope that helps! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* plough ahead and start coding right away: start with *analysing the task*

*Greedy* means *take the best possible next step* (**never** looking back; look-ahead limited or disallowed).
Let dₓ be the distance for day x, and have a look at hotels at 150, 200, 250 miles:
- if cost was 200-dₓ,
  total cost is 150 with a first distance of 200 as well as with 150
- if cost was (200-dₓ)²,
  total cost is 22500 with a first distance of 200, only 12500 with 150:
  you're best off with *each absolute difference as close to all others as possible*
  - without (full) look-ahead, you don't *know* all remaining:
    next difference as close to *expected average remaining* as possible
  - all other things being equal, you're better off with fewer day trips than with more
- with a look-ahead of 1, the single-day trip with cost 50 and 2500 becomes an option.

---

`how I can write a Java code that solves this problem`?
With *greedy* revisited and one (more) example considered (same as always):

- **don't** write down an algorithm (yet):
- **Give *testing* a solution serious thought**
  If not in analysis, *this* is where *problems with the task definition* are bound to become apparent: Is `200 miles` an upper limit? (Am I allowed to switch direction?)
  Code a test, make it check example tasks and results. *Make it flag erroneous results*(, only).
- Only then start sketching a solution.
  Habitually, I take a detour/shortcut here:
  I start a source file (or continue the one with the test(s)) and put down a description of the task to accomplish using the documentation convention of the programming tool of choice, with Java, that would be [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).
  I sketch the solution, syntactically as comments in a form easily split (Java: `//` line comments)
- check the solution sketched: does any simplification suggest itself?
  If it looks complex: can restrictions be dropped to allow a simpler approach give the same results?
  It may save time in the end to implement that approach first, even if revisiting the restrictions dropped results in rejecting it as a solution.
  (Here, [Daniele's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679999/3789665) was worth a try *if* your approach looked *significantly* more complex.)
- with a maintainable description of *what* to do *how*, you're ready to code